# Java Applet AWT-EventQueue-1 ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, applet, awt-eventqueue

I created a Vector called lines that stores the coordinate points of the end points of drawn line. It accomplishes the task that I want by drawing lines from the stored coordinates but produces the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 10
    at java.util.Vector.get(Vector.java:748)
    at DrawPad.paint(DrawPad.java:149)
    at java.awt.Container.update(Container.java:1995)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(RepaintArea.java:255)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:232)
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(WComponentPeer.java:358)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4967)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check to see if the element exists before calling lines.get(i). Also, use lines.size() instead of lines.capacity().

```
for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i += 4)
{
    if((i+3) < lines.size())
    {
        g.drawLine(lines.get(i), lines.get(i + 1), lines.get(i + 2), lines.get(i + 3));
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help.

Comment: I deleted the code since this was an assignment and I didn't want other students finding it. Just for your information.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lines.capacity(); i += 4)
            g.drawLine(lines.get(i), lines.get(i + 1), lines.get(i + 2), lines.get(i + 3));
```

You are incrementing i by 4 each iteration of the for loop. Which means the first loop you are accessing the 0, 1, 2, and 3 elements of the lines Vector. The next loop you are accessing 4, 5, 6, 7. Next you are accessing 8, 9, 10, 11. The lines Vector may not have that many elements in it.

Comment: I have to look at 4 points at a time ... Each time I press and then release my mouse, it adds 4 points.

Comment: Create a Line object that has 4 integers in it. Each time you add a line, add a new Line(1, 2, 3, 4) to your lines Vector. Then your loop will just iterate over each line object like so: for(int i = 0; i < lines.capacity(); i++)
            g.drawLine(lines.a, lines.b, lines.c, lines.d);

Comment: I'll edit my answer so I can post the formatted code

Comment: Scratch what I said about the line object. I added a new answer.